# System.Exception finger print didn't match while runnig test scripts in xamarin UI Testing for mobile app testing

Tags: visual-studio, mobile, xamarin, automated-tests

I got a error i n mobile app testing.

System.Exception finger print didn't match  while runnig test scripts in xamarin UI Testing for mobile app testing

Anyone know the answer please advise.

Thanks!